# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre StackOverflowError y OutOfMemorryError y como podemos evitarlos en la aplicacion?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Me han saltado estos dos errores en Java y me gustaría saber qué diferencia hay entre ellos, y cómo se pueden evitar ambos?.

Comment: Tu proceso debe estar consumiendo o robando demasiada memoria de manera recursiva, la solución: Escribe buen código.

Comment: Sebastian, tu pregunta es interesante pero podrías agregar en que casos obtuviste estos errores, considero que sería buen ejemplo para otros desarrolladores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**StackOverflowError**

[image: StackOverFlowError]
Se produce cuando la pila de llamadas a métodos entre clases se desborda debido a un número excesivo y nuestra aplicación se rompe.
Suele producirse cuando codificamos mal la condición de salida en ún método recursivo.

Deberías saber cuantas llamadas soporta nuestra pila antes de romperse, para después contar nuestras llamadas y probar si realmente superan este número en un caso real, o solo lo superan porque nuestro algoritmo está mal codificado.

**OutOfMemoryError:**

[image: OutOfMemoryError]

La memoria de la Máquina Virtual se divide en varias regiones. Una de estas regiones es el **PermGen**, el área de memoria utilizada para, entre otras cosas, guardar el metadata de las clases como los atributos y sus tipos de datos, métodos etc. Esta memoria es de tipo non-heap. Las instancias de las clases se cargan en la memoria de tipo heap, a la que se van añadiendo y eliminando las instancias de las clases según se van utilizando y eliminándose por el recolector de basura (Garbage Collector, en adelante GC).

El valor por defecto del espacio **PermGen es de 64 Mb** en la máquina virtual (VM) de Sun. Este valor es suficiente normalmente para las aplicaciones que corren de forma independiente. En el caso de una aplicación que corra en un servidor web tipo Tomcat o un servidor de aplicaciones, hay casos en los que este valor no es suficiente.

**En primer lugar**, **es posible que la aplicación necesite más espacio** por su propia arquitectura. Las librerías Spring e Hibernate son librerías grandes, que cargan muchas clases y además hacen uso de proxies y carga dinámica de clases que hacen uso del espacio PermGen por lo que puede que los 64Mb no sean suficientes. Este caso se da cuando la excepción con el error se produce nada mas arrancar el servidor web o de aplicaciones o al acceder a la aplicación.

- **Para solventar este problema bastará con aumentar el tamaño máximo de
  la memoria de tipo PermGen**

**En segundo lugar,** la causa más probable de una excepción java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space failure se produce cuando la aplicación se reinstala en el servidor sin reiniciar el servidor. La forma de reinstalar las aplicaciones es eliminando el classloader que cargó la aplicación por primera vez y creando un nuevo classloader para la nueva instancia de la aplicación. En teoría, esto proporciona una forma limpia de reinstalar aplicaciones, pero si el servidor web o de aplicaciones guarda una referencia al classloader antiguo, se produce una fuga de memoria (memory leak) y el resultado es que tendremos las clases de la aplicación cargadas dos veces en memoria.

Por el momento te dejo un enlace muy interesante, aunque en inglés, acerca de posibles causas de fugas de memoria en java: 
[Fuga de Memoria](https://developer.atlassian.com/platform/open-source/)

Comment: no era ese tipo de imagenes , era en imagenes como quedaba la memoria y el procesador

Comment: Si vas a responder este tipo de preguntas al menos debe ser adecuada la información.

Comment: @Elenasys en que sentido la informacion proporcionada no es correcta? Yo lo que echo de menos es que no habla de aumentar el heap con los switches `-Xms` y `-Xmx`